# Find the value $\sum_{n=a}^b\frac1{\sin (2^{n+3})}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, summation, telescopic-series

Find the value of: $$\sum_{n=0}^{10}\frac1{\sin (2^{n+3})}$$

I'm stuck on this problem, can someone please help?

Comment: Is there any reason to imagine that this has a sensible closed form?  Numerically it is $1.16991373\cdots$ if that's what you want.

Comment: @lulu it is equal to $\cot4-\cot(2^{13})$

Comment: Degrees or radians?  The degree symbol has disappeared.

Comment: Radians${}{}{}$

Comment: $\sum_{n=0}^k\frac1{\sin 2^{n+3}}=\cot4-\cot(2^{k+3})$ where everything is in radians

Comment: @MathStackexchangeIsNotSoBad  Oh, that's quite nice.   Thanks!   Is that obvious?

Comment: @no...but yeah I beleive you can prove it...not me tho

Answer (score 6):

Note that

$$\begin{align}\cot(2^k)-\cot(2^{k+1})&=\frac{\sin (2^{k+1})\cos( 2^{k})-\sin (2^{k})\cos(2^{k+1})}{\sin (2^k)\sin( 2^{k+1})}\\
\\
&=\frac{\sin( 2^{k+1}- 2^{k})}{\sin( 2^k)\sin (2^{k+1})}\\
\\
&=\frac{1}{\sin (2^{k+1})}\end{align}$$

Therefore,

$$\sum_{k=a}^{b}\frac{1}{\sin 2^{k+1}}=\cot(2^a)-\cot(2^{b+1})$$